# how many object types in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
...
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

// write the countCandyTypes function here
function countCandyTypes(inventory) {
}
...
```

i need help looping through and counting the candies in this inventory array. theyre asking me to count the types of candy (twizzlers, sour patch kids, milks duds and now and laters for a total of 4.) i need help writing the function with a return.

Comment: Share what did you try.

Comment: You need to actually try something. This question is extensively covered in other SO posts. Google "How to iterate json array" and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to count. If you just want the number of different types of candy and you know that each object in the array represents a unique type of candy then this would work:

```
function countCandyTypes(inventory) {
  return inventory.length;
}
```

If you could have multiple objects representing the same type of candy, then this would work:

```
function countCandyTypes(inventory) {
  var types = [];
  for (const record of inventory) {
    if (!types.includes(record.candy) {
      types.push(record.candy);
    }
  }
  return types.length;
}
```

If you really only care about the number of candies and not the types:

```
function countCandyTypes(inventory) {
  var count = 0;
  for (const record of inventory) {
    count += record.inStock;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: thank u! that definitely worked. what if i wanted a function that did the totalInStock?

Comment: I need more information than just `totalInStock`. The third function I posted may answer this question. If not, is there a parameter being passed to the function like `totalInStock(typeOfCandy)`?

Answer (score 1):

I undestood you would like to count the entire amount of candies.

```js
let inventory = [{
    candy: "Twizzlers",
    inStock: 180,
    weeklyAverage: 200
  },
  {
    candy: "Sour Patch Kids",
    inStock: 90,
    weeklyAverage: 100
  },
  {
    candy: "Milk Duds",
    inStock: 300,
    weeklyAverage: 170
  },
  {
    candy: "Now and Laters",
    inStock: 150,
    weeklyAverage: 40
  }
];


// write the countCandyTypes function here
function countCandyTypes(inventory) {
  let sum = inventory.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    acc += elem.inStock;
    return acc;
  }, 0)
  console.log(sum)
}

countCandyTypes(inventory);
```